# opening a layout (xml) inside a fragment instead of string text input

Tags: android

Problem: I was modifying a small app where three tabs are there in fragment but all refers to text string. I wanted to use layout xml so that I can make good graphics in it. How can I do it in this code:
Information_tab refers to a string where I can put text, but I want a layout.

```
public class AdapterInformation extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

public AdapterInformation(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int index) {
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    int imgResId = 0;
    int tab = 0;
    int colorResId = 0;
    switch (index) {
        case 0:
            tab = R.string.information_tab1;
            break;
        case 1:
            tab = R.string.information_tab2;
            break;
        case 2:
            tab = R.string.information_tab3;
            break;
    }
    bundle.putInt("image", imgResId);
    bundle.putInt("tab",tab);
    bundle.putInt("color", colorResId);
    SwipeTabFragment swipeTabFragment = new SwipeTabFragment();
    swipeTabFragment.setArguments(bundle);
    return swipeTabFragment;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 3;
}}
```

Comment: Can you be a bit more clear on what you're trying to do?

Comment: I have an app it has three tabs and the content in it is text. I want a layout kind of interface instead of just text. Here in the code you can see tab = R.string.information_tab1. Information_tab1 is text string. I want to have layout in tabs so that I can make it interactive and good.

Answer (score 0):

you can add fragment layout like this.

```
private void setupViewPager(final ViewPager viewPager) {
        final ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new OneFragment(), "Pending Upload");
        adapter.addFragment(new TwoFragment(), "Complete Upload");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
 }
```

and your fragmentPagerAdapter code is like this:

```
     public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager)
        {
            super(manager);
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
            return POSITION_NONE;
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position)
        {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }

        public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
        }
    }
```

and also add your setupViewPager method in onCreate()

```
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);

    setupViewPager(viewPager)
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
```

> Note:    Do not use getItemPosition() method if its possible.. it
>   will produce redundancy of your listItems or ArrayList.. bcz every
>   time you swipe to other layout it will refresh page automatically..
>   its good if want this facility.. but you have write some code
>   regarding to handle this method..  and its also going to slow your
>   swipe animation if you have large amount of data.

For more information about tab layout and fragment:  you can refer this one:

http://www.androidhive.info/2015/09/android-material-design-working-with-tabs/

Comment: Can you explain a bit where to add these codes.. I am new to android

Comment: ok.. just replace your AdapterInformation class to my ViewPagerAdapter Class.

Comment: @Tony Stark   i hope my updated answer solve your problem